# Proxy or gateway between application and database server

Tags: proxy, database, application

We are going through implementing ISO 27001 processes we have a requirement of having a proxy server between the application and database server, can someone suggest an architecture and tools to use?

Comment: Ask your question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ And provide much more details and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It can be almost anything. The key is no direct access to the database by components other than the proxy. It could mean an application server front ending the database, but there are other solutions. For example, using HAProxy in front of MySQL, or AWS has their own custom proxy for RDS.